# Writing UIImage to file locks up UI even on background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiimage

I'm using the following code to save some images and I'm executing this on a background thread using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^ {
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array_of_objects_implementing_NSCoding toFile:myFile];
});
```

I have objects implementing the NSCoding protocol in the array, and each of those objects has an array with an image associated with it. Every time I call this however when the image is big enough (something taken from the photo gallery), the UI freezes. Here's the code to save the image:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    NSLog(@"Beginning encoding.");
    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image);
    [encoder encodeObject:imageData forKey@"image"];
    NSLog(@"Encoding completed.");
}
```

I did a profile of the apps CPU usage through execution and while the UI is freezing, CPU usage spikes to 100% with 85% of it being directed at the line using "UIImagePNGRepresentation". Also, when this is called, "Beginning encoding." is printed to console but "Encoding completed." never is.

Why is this locking up the UI even if it's on a background thread?

Comment: UIImage conforms to NSCoding - why not just have it encode itself?

Comment: The system I'm working in has been using this method of encoding for multiple versions. If I change it now I'd also have to read the data in 'initWithCoder' to read it as a UIImage. I can do it, but I'd prefer not to deviate from what I have especially when this code works for slightly smaller images. I'll try your suggestion and report back with how it works.

Comment: Also, updated question with a bit more info... it doesn't look like the encoding function is reaching the end.

Comment: What does Instruments say? Which functions/methods are called by UIImagePNGRepresentation when it hangs? You might need to enable the "Record Waiting Threads" option in the Time Profiler instrument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use UIImagePNGRepresentation from a background thread. Apple has made some of UIKit thread safe but not all of it. Try using CGImage or ImageIO calls instead.

Comment: This is accurate. Moving this call to the main thread removes the lockup and increases the speed of the call, however it still slows down user interaction (table scrolling is choppy).

I decided to resize the image before saving to cut down on execution time. Thanks for the help!